# Hangman Game Help replacing chars with strings (java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, chars

I pretty much know how to do a lot of this project except replace the "_ _ _ *"of the hidden word with characteristics, ex: "* o o _". How do I replace a characteristic with a string and output the data. Ignore the notes, they are just some random thoughts of code. Here is what I have so far:

```
  import java.util.Random;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class ProjectNum2 {

    // Alex Berencz

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        String letterguess;
        String wordguess;
        String hangmanwords = "";
        char letter;
        String con = "yes";
        String quit = "no";
        int computer = 0;
        int player = 0;
        boolean done = false;
        int guess = 6;

        // while(!done){

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Hangman Word game!");

        String[] hangmanWords = { "apple", "triangle", "assassin", "mercenary",
                "loop", "snake", "lion", "algorithm", "turtle", "return",
                "message", "heart", "halloween", "door", "fruit", "band",
                "married", "summer", "choice", "elephant" };
        String[] spaces = { "_ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _ _ _",
                "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _",
                "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _ _",
                "_ _ _ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _",
                "_ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _ _",
                "_ _ _ _ _ _", "_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _" };

        int index = (int) RandomWord(hangmanWords, spaces, hangmanwords);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Choose a letter or enter zero to guess the word: ");
        letterguess = kbd.next();
        String guesscomplete = "0";
        String fixedkey = letterguess.toLowerCase();
        char[] charkey = new char[letterguess.length()];

        // for(int x=0; x>letterguess.charAt(x); x++){

        // charkey[x]=letterguess.charAt(x);

        if (letterguess.equals(guesscomplete)) {
            System.out.println("Guess the word! ");
            wordguess = kbd.next();

            if (wordguess.equals(hangmanWords[index])) {
                System.out.println("That is correct!");
                player++;

                System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
                String again = kbd.next();

                if (again.equals(quit)) {
                    System.out.println("Computer wins: " + computer
                            + " Player wins: " + player);
                    System.out.println("See you later!");

                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("That is not correct!");
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
                    again = kbd.next();
                    computer++;

                }

            }

        }

        while (hangmanWords[index].contains(letterguess)) {
            System.out.println(hangmanWords[index].replace(hangmanWords[index],
                    letterguess));
            System.out
                    .println("Choose a letter or enter zero to guess the word: ");
            letterguess = kbd.next();

        }

        if (!hangmanWords[index].contains(letterguess)) {
            guess--;
            System.out.println("The letter is not in the word. You have "
                    + guess + " more guesses.");
            System.out
                    .println("Choose a letter or enter zero to guess the word: ");
            letterguess = kbd.next();

            if (guess == 0) {
                computer++;

            }

        }

    }

    // }

    // }

    private static Object RandomWord(String[] hangmanWords, String[] spaces,
            String hangmanwords) {

        Random ranIndex = new Random();
        int index = ranIndex.nextInt(hangmanWords.length);
        hangmanwords = spaces[index];
        System.out.print(hangmanwords);
        return (index);

    }

  }
```

Here is my output:

```
 Welcome to the Hangman Word game!
_ _ _ _ _ _ _
Choose a letter or enter zero to guess the word: 
 a
a
Choose a letter or enter zero to guess the word:
```

Comment: You need to use a `StringBuilder` and a loop.  Loop over the "secret" word and for each character that matches the user's guesses, replace the character in the output with the corresponding character...Now, if you do this cleverly, you will only need to do this once for guess

Comment: You could also use Regular Expressions (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#introduction) to hide all characters within the answer that haven't yet been found.

Comment: I have to say that the title is really poorly made.  It does not help anyone in having a high level understand on what your question is supposed to ask.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder has a [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace-int-int-java.lang.String-) method that takes a start and end index.
The replace method on String only take existing characters to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do replace like that.

You only need to think of a way to display the answer according to the "guessed characters".

For example,

```
for each char c in answer {
    if exists in guessedChars {
        print c
    } else {
        print _
    }
}
```